# MoreLikeThis Query, field priority?

Tags: lucene

I don't really know, how MoreLikeThis query works. I have this question, suppose, I have two documents, I have some fields and one field for country. Now, one document has country field with value 'Australia' and other document has country field with value 'England'.

Considering, all other fields are identical, now, If MoreLikeThis Query is run on a document, will it return the other one? Only country fields are different.

And, is there any way to give a field maximum priority? like in this case, 'Country', so that lucene return morelikethis items specific to a country?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `BooleanQuery` to combine the MLT query with a query for the desired "country" value.

For example:

```java
MoreLikeThis mlt = new MoreLikeThis(reader);
Query mltQuery = mlt.like(docNo);
Query countryQuery = new TermQuery("country", "england");
Query finalQuery = BooleanQuery.Builder()
    .add(mltQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
    .add(countryQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
    .build();
```